# Firebase user delete not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am following newest version of Firebase Google Web SDK. Everything from login to sign up and sign out works just fine. I want to let users delete their own accounts and followed the API reference for `firebase.User` class. Also I read their docs about [managing users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

This is the code I use:

```
function deleteAccount () {
  console.log('delete account!!')
  const auth = firebase.auth()
  console.log({auth})

  auth.delete().then(function () {
    console.log('delete successful?')
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    console.log({user})
    store.dispatch(forgetUser())
    routerReset('GetStarted')
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log({error})
    // An error happened.
  })
}
```

The function `delete` appears to work from `firebase.Auth` object and resolves the promise. If doing the same with `signOut` the log presents an undefined object, however here:

```
console.log({user}) // { user: Firebase.User object }
```

No error is emitted.

NOTE: this is a react-native app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be missing a reference to `currentUser`.

From the [Firebase documentation on deleting a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user):

> You can delete a user account with the `delete` method. For example:
>
> ```
> var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
>
> user.delete().then(function() {
>   // User deleted.
> }, function(error) {
>   // An error happened.
> });
> ```
>
> **Important**: To delete a user, the user must have signed in recently. See Re-authenticate a user.

As said, your code doesn't reference `currentUser`. I'm not sure what calling `delete` on the [auth object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) itself does.

**Update**: I just ran this to validate the behavior:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.delete().then(function () {
  console.log('delete successful?')
  console.log(app.auth().currentUser)
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error({error})
})
```

At first I got a 400, with the body of the response saying that it'd been too long since I signed in. After re-authenticating and trying again, I got:

> delete successful?
>
> null

Comment: This piece of code behaves in exacly the same way as described above. I ignore why.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I'll retry – hopefully I was wrong before. Since this is a react-native project, slight differences may occur on opaque APIs (e.g: internally using Promise resolve in a different way or `fetch` vs `XmlHttpRequest`. I am currently using a workaround with `onAuthStateChange`.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a user, the user must have signed in recently.

Comment: That is the case, else it should throw an error indicating to do so, and not just resolve the promise. Right?